# Facebook Messenger API Send Base64 Image

Tags: node.js, facebook, base64, chatbot

I am currently builidng a chatbot with nodejs. I have my Images stored in a MongoDB now I want to send a Image to facebook but I only got the Base64 String and Facebook wants an URL. Anyone who knows a solution for that?

Comment: _“and Facebook wants an URL”_ - upload via URL is only _one_ of the ways offered; there are others. (And before you reflexively ask which ones those are now, please go read the documentation.)

Comment: Convert base64 to image and save to the folder which should be static and public inside node app and pass url of your image to fb. For eg : yourappUrl/public/images/generateImage.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In php you make a script to render the image, like http://someurl?img=base64string I think in node is pretty much the same workaround. Make sense for you?